# Excel Median range

Tags: excel, function, range, median

Search column A for the first two cells in the column that display/have a number within the range of + or - .5A1…i.e. (A1-.5) & (A1+.5). Once found – Find the median of the 3 values & post the median to a new column. Search column A for the first two cells in the column that display/have a number within the range of + or - .5A2…i.e. (A2-.5) & (A2+.5). Once found – Find the median of the 3 values & post the median to a new column. Continue function through the entire list.

```
OUTPUT: Column C is the Medians
COLUMN B   Column C

43         43

42.9       

43.93      43.93

42.5       42.50

44.55      44.55

39         39

39.97      
41.5      
39.25      
38.95     
38.27
38.95
38.27
38.95
39.42
40.49      40.49
40.43
```

I've tried

```
=MEDIAN(IF(AND(B2:B20>B2,B2:B20<B2+0.5,B2:B20<B2,B2:B20>B2-0.5),B2:B20))

=MEDIAN(IF(AND(B4+0.5)<=B4:B52>=(B4-0.5),IF(B4:B52<=B4+0.5,B4:B52)))

=MEDIAN(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B17,ROW(B17:B115)-ROW(B17),0)),B17:B115))

=MEDIAN(IF($B$2:$B$12=$E2,IF($C$2:$C$12=F$1,$B$2:$B$12)))
```

I've changed some of the above functions to try and get them to work, but have had no success.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output of the function for your sample data?  Your question is fairly clear but I think can still be interpreted in a number of ways.

Comment: My bad I'm new here so I'm learning how to post things properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There got it everything's in the block! Looks good